exception handling Firebase Admin .Net
how do I handle the invalid mail exception, I need to perform certain actions if the mail is not correct
  public async Task<string> RegiserAsynh(RegisterData registerData)
  {
      try
      {
          var userArgs = new UserRecordArgs()
          {
              Email = registerData.Email,
              Password = registerData.Password,
              DisplayName = registerData.Name,
              EmailVerified = true,
          };
       UserRecord UserRecord = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserAsync(userArgs);
       Users newuser = new Users()
       {
           Email = UserRecord.Email,
           Uid = UserRecord.Uid,
           Name = UserRecord.DisplayName,
           LastSignInDate = UserRecord.UserMetaData.LastSignInTimestamp,
           СreationDate = UserRecord.UserMetaData.LastRefreshTimestamp

       };
       _IUserRepository.RegisterEF(newuser);

          return UserRecord.Uid;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          return ex.Message;
      }

  }

I tried to use catch (FirebaseAuthException ex) but it didn't work,
I've read the Firebase documentation about the types of errors, but I can't figure out how to track them and check which error occurred
documentation

Can you be more specific? Sounds to me that you just need to debug the code check the  actually thrown exception and then when you know what exception it is is handle that one accordingly.

@Ralf ,the user enters the data, and a request is sent to firebase. I need to handle the "email-already-exists" and "invalid-email" exceptions, but I can't catch it.

You have debugged the code and seen what exception is thrown in those mentioned cases?

It would be helpful if you specified what exactly "didn't work" with catching specific exceptions. What code did you try? How did you expect it to behave, and what did it do instead?

I get an exception, but how do I check in if which exception was caused specifically

The docu for the mentioned FirebaseAuthException says it has a AuthErrorCode property to check the different causes.
